# Intellij: Excluded java class getting considered in make/compilation

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

As per https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/compiler-excludes.html, I excluded one of the java class which was used only for some scripting purposes. While I am running some Junit whose configuration has a before launch task "Make", it is trying to make the project and showing errors in this excluded java class. How is it possible? Is it a bug in my intellij idea ultimate mac version 14.1.4 build 1532? Or am I missing something here?

Strangely, I excluded two classes and this problem is coming in only one of them, i.e. the second excluded file is indeed being excluded and not showing compilation failure during MAKE.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the project structure?  Have you double-checked in Project Settings that your exclusions are "sticking" ?

Comment: Thanks for commenting Tim. I tried further by adding some more exclusions and all of them are successfully getting excluded, except one of them, so it may not really be Intellij bug, may be something related with that particular structure. For the time being, I have made that whole package EXCLUDED instead of excluding that single java class. Unfortunately, I cannot share the project structure/code for further help as it's company code.